# Using Polly to retry one time with a 200 ms wait on an Async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, polly, retry-logic

I'm trying to do the following using Polly. I have an `ExecuteTask` async method, and I want to perform a conditional retry with a 200 ms wait. This is what I have so far:

#### The policy

```
AsyncRetryPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = AsyncPolicy
    .HandleResult<SomeData>(s => s.IsCorrect == false)
    .WaitAndRetry(1,
    sleepDurationProvider: (retryCount, status, ctx) =>
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    },
    onRetry: (response, timeSpan, retryCount, ctx) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received a response of {response.Result}, retrying {retryCount}.");
    });
```

#### The to-be-decorated method

```
private static async Task<SomeData> ExecuteTask()
{
    return new SomeData() { IsCorrect= false };
}
```

#### The execution

```
var rslt = retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
        return await ExecuteTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
    });
```

`SomeData` is just a class with a bool property, called `IsCorrect`.

I can't seem the figure out how to define this policy. `AsyncPolicy` does not contain a `HandleResult()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You start by creating a `PolicyBuilder<SomeData>` via `Policy.HandleResult<>()`, then you produce an async policy by calling `WaitAndRetryAsync`. You just need to be careful to get all the delegate signatures correct or it won't recognize the method. It can help with debugging if you pass an explicit type into the `WaitAndRetryAsync<>()` method.

```
AsyncRetryPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<SomeData>(s => s.IsCorrect == false)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync<SomeData>(1,
    sleepDurationProvider: _ =>
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    },
    onRetry: (response, timeSpan, retryCount, ctx) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received a response of {response}, retrying {retryCount}.");
    });

var rslt = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    return await ExecuteTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Policy.HandleResult` and invoke `WaitAndRetryAsync` on it:

```cs
AsyncRetryPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<SomeData>(s => s.IsCorrect == false)
     .WaitAndRetryAsync(1,
         sleepDurationProvider: _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
         onRetry: (response, timeSpan, retryCount, ctx) =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Received a response of {response}, retrying {retryCount}.");
         });

var rslt = await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await ExecuteTask().ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of Polly we can use the Builder Pattern to define policies:

1. You can start to define a policy either via the [`Policy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.cs) or via the [`Policy<TResult>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.TResult.cs) [classes](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Non-generic-and-generic-policies)
2. They expose **static** methods so, whenever you are calling the [`Handle<TException>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.HandleSyntax.cs#L10) or [`HandleResult<TResult>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.HandleSyntax.cs#L44) on it you will receive a [`PolicyBuilder`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBuilder.cs) or a [`PolicyBuilder<TResult>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBuilder.cs#L70) instance
3. They expose **instance** methods so, if you want to define additional triggers then you can do that via [`Or<TException>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBuilder.OrSyntax.cs#L12), [`OrInner<TException>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBuilder.OrSyntax.cs#L35), or [`OrResult<TResult>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBuilder.OrSyntax.cs#L86)
   3.1. Each instance method returns the builder
4. There are **extension** methods to define the required behaviour, like [`WaitAndRetry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Retry/RetrySyntax.cs#L177) or [`WaitAndRetryForeverAsync<TResult>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Retry/AsyncRetryTResultSyntax.cs#L846)
   4.1 These return with [`RetryPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Retry/RetryPolicy.cs) and [`AsyncRetryPolicy<TResult>`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/AsyncPolicy.TResult.cs) classes respectively

In order words:

- *Get a builder instance*: decide that your to-be-decorated thing is a method or a function
- *Configure the builder*: define the trigger(s)
- *Build the policy*: define the actual behaviour

---

There are so many classes and interfaces in Polly and one can easily lost there. Let me try to guide you through these with an example: synchronous retry policy for a method:

#### Classes

- [`RetryEngine`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Retry/RetryEngine.cs): This is the actual implementation and it has many responsibilities: check whether the policy should be triggered, calculate the sleep duration, call user provided delegate, execute the decorated method, etc.
- [`RetryPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Retry/RetryPolicy.cs): It is a thin wrapper around the engine. In other words it is the publicly exposed API to reach the engine

  - Because the retry policy is stateless that's why this wrapper is thin
  - But for instance the [Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerPolicy.cs) policy is [stateful](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Statefulness-of-policies), so its policy class stores state and a reference to a controller << *not so thin*
- [`PolicyBase`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBase.cs): This contains the common elements for all kinds of policies regardless they are defined as sync or async and regardless defined for method or function
- [`Policy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.cs): This class defines many common functionality for building a policy, executing it ([`Execute` or `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.ExecuteOverloads.cs)) and [handling context](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Policy.ContextAndKeys.cs), etc.

#### Interfaces

- [`IRetryPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/Retry/IRetryPolicy.cs): It is just a marker interface

  - it is specially useful in case of usage of [`PolicyRegistry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry)
- [`ISyncPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/ISyncPolicy.cs): It defines the `Execute` and `ExecuteAndCapture` overloads
- [`IPolicy`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/IsPolicy.cs): It is just an other marker interface, it defines a single property called `PolicyKey`

  - It is set [inside the `PolicyBase`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/src/Polly/PolicyBase.ContextAndKeys.cs#L13)

---

Because of the above ones the following policy definitions are (more or less) identical:

```
AsyncRetryPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<SomeData>(...
IRetryPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<SomeData>(...
AsyncPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = Policy<SomeData>.HandleResult(...
IAsyncPolicy<SomeData> retryPolicy = Policy<SomeData>.HandleResult(...
```