# Polly and async method: cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate Task<HttpResponseMessage>

Tags: c#, .net, polly, retry-logic

I am trying to use Polly to wrap an async method. How I get an error with my method, I try this:

```
var myResult = await _politicaReintentar.ExecuteAsync(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
```

But I get an error that tells it cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, and the error is marked in `await Task.Delay(1000)`.

In the documentation the way to use is  this:

```
var response = await timeoutPolicy
    .ExecuteAsync(
      async () => await FooNotHonoringCancellationAsync(), // Execute a delegate which takes no CancellationToken and does not respond to cancellation.
      );
```

I don't see the problem, I use `async` and `await` as parameters of `ExecuteAsync`.

How should I call my async method?

Thanks.

EDIT: this is the policy:

```
_politicaReintentar = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError() // HttpRequestException, 5XX and 408
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt));
```

Comment: the copied documentation shows a comma, do you need one in your implementation?

Comment: Could you please share with us the policy definition? Could you please share with us the exact compilation error?

Comment: Btw you don't need to use async await inside the ExecuteAsync if you only have a single async method call.

Comment: I have added the policy.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Based on the shared the policy definition my answer still stands. So, your policy can be used  against function which returns `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. `Task.Delay` returns a `Task`, they are not compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the so far provided information, I **assume** you have defined a policy where the to-be-decorated async method should return an `HttpReponseMessage`.

`Task.Delay` does not return with a `HttpResponseMessage`. Your policy definition must be compatible with the to-be-decorated method return type.

---

**UPDATE #1**

> I really would like to learn how to execute an async method with Polly and retry 3 times, for example. In this case, a basic case is to execute a Task.Delay()

I don't want to repeat here the documentation of Polly so, let me give you some really short summary.

In case of Polly the policy definition and its execution are separated.

#### Definition

The definition is done via several builder functions. In all cases you have to define the following three:

- The to-be-decorated action is sync/async and method/function
- The trigger(s) for which the policy should be fire
- The chosen resilience action and its configuration

In case of your `_politicaReintentar` these are the following:

```
HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
```

It is [equivalent with the following](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Extensions.Http/blob/69fd292bc603cb3032e57b028522737255f03a49/src/Polly.Extensions.Http/HttpPolicyExtensions.cs#L28):

```
Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
  .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
  .OrTransientHttpStatusCode()
```

- The to-be-decorated function should return a `HttpResponseMessage`
- It should trigger either for `HttpRequestException`
- Or it should trigger if the [status code is 408 or 5xx](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Extensions.Http/blob/69fd292bc603cb3032e57b028522737255f03a49/src/Polly.Extensions.Http/HttpPolicyExtensions.cs#L12)

```
.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(retryAttempt));
```

- It says that the to-be-decorated method is async
- The retry policy should be used as a chosen resiliency action
- With at most 3 retry attempts, with predefined sleep duration between attempts

If you are interested more about this, please check the following SO topics:

- [Polly WaitAndRetryAsync vs WaitAndRetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095394/polly-waitandretryasync-vs-waitandretry/73095879#73095879)
- [Using Polly to retry one time with a 200 ms wait on an Async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392165/using-polly-to-retry-one-time-with-a-200-ms-wait-on-an-async-method/75396161#75396161)

#### Execution

Depending on the policy definition you can either call `Execute` or `ExecuteAsync`. So, you have to know upfront what do you want to decorate and define your policy accordingly.

Polly also exposes methods like `ExecuteAndCapture` and `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync`. The different between these and the above ones is that the latter do not throw exception rather captures either the result of the method or the exception into a `PolicyResult` object.

#### Back to your example

Retrying the `Task.Delay` unconditionally is not supported by Polly. You have to have either a `Handle<>` or `HandleResult<>` to define a trigger. For the sake of simplicity I will cancel the `Task.Delay` which will throw `OperationCanceledException` and that would be our trigger.

```
var retry = Policy
    .Handle<OperationCanceledException>()
    .RetryAsync(3, (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Retried"));
```

```
await retry.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
     var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
     await Task.Delay(2000, cts.Token);
});
```

I've added some logging to the policy for clarity.

Here you can find the related [dotnet fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AkiUhm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't know how to do it. Could you show an example?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía What exactly do you want to achieve? Use your policy as suppose to? Define a policy for Task.Delay? Or something else?

Comment: I really would like to learn how to execute an async method with Polly and retry 3 times, for example. In this case, a basic case is to execute a Task.Delay().

Comment: Well, when I use Policy like in your example, it works, but when I use HttpPolicyExtensions, how I indicate in my post, it is when I get the error. So how could I configure HttpPolicyExtensions to can use HandleTransientHttpError?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía The HandleTransientHttpError is suitable to decorate an HttpClient instance. So, that should be used to decorate idempotent network requests. Is it clear?

Comment: Does it means that I can't use HandleTransientHttpError  to execute a method that doesn't return HttpResponseMessage? If this is true, how could I handle the transient exceptions with polly? With Handle<Expcetion>()?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía The `HandleTransientHttpError` is a predefined policy for common HttpClient based transient errors. You can extend that with `Or<Exception>()` to trigger for any exception if you wish.

Comment: Then if I understand correctly, I should to Policy.Handle<Exception1>().Or<Exception2>.Or<Exception3>()...?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Yes, you can do that or you can provide there a predicate function like this `.Handle<Exception>(ex => ShouldTriggerFor(ex))` or in short `.Handle<Exception>(ShouldTriggerFor)`. The `ShouldTriggerFor` could check the exception type and return true if should be retry should be triggered otherwise false.